# How to apply METIS partitioning on Gephi graph

Tags: gephi, metis

I need to do a partition of 2 components with METIS algorithm on a  Gephi's graph but I don't find the way to do it. Apparently METIS use .graph files but Gephi doesn't have an option/plugin to export graph in that format.

I'm using this library for METIS partitiong: http://glaros.dtc.umn.edu/gkhome/metis/metis/overview

Answer (score 0):

Finally I could do it by exporting the graph to GML format, then I opened it in python and with this library https://metis.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ I could run metis